# MS Access Report

Tags: vba

Is there a way to use the user's input (start and end) dates in a report text box? For example, I have an Access query that will prompt the user for a start date and end date. I then used that query to run a report for just that date range. But I would like to use the start and stop date that the user enters, in the report title. Can anyone help with this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the values you want to use to global variables and then use the `Report_Load()` event sub to place those values as the report loads.

Global assignments must be done in a module, you can't do it from the report or form's code-behind. I've named my module GlobalAssignments.

```
Global startdate As String
Global enddate As String

Sub SetStartDate(val As Date)
    startdate = CStr(val)
End Sub

Sub SetEndDate(val As Date)
    enddate = CStr(val)
End Sub
```

In the form you're using to get the dates from the user, something like this:

```
Private Sub cmd_RunReport_Click()
    Dim startdate As Date
    Dim enddate As Date
    With Me
        startdate = .Txt_StartDate.Value
        enddate = .txt_EndDate.Value
    End With
    
    GlobalAssignments.SetStartDate startdate
    GlobalAssignments.SetEndDate enddate
    DoCmd.OpenReport "Rpt_DateRange", acViewPreview 'Pretty sure it has to be preview
End Sub
```

And in the Report:

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
    Me.lbl_Header.Caption = "Date Report for range: " & startdate & " - " & enddate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using the startdate and enddate parameters in the query's criteria - just add the parameters to the Field list. Then you can simply include them in the text box ControlSource

Say your query is

```
SELECT myTable.* FROM myTable WHERE myTable.myDateField BETWEEN [Start Date] and [EndDate]
```

Change it to

```
SELECT myTable.*, ReportStartDate:[Start Date], ReportEndDate:[EndDate] 
FROM myTable WHERE myTable.myDateField BETWEEN [Start Date] and [End Date]
```

Then, assuming your Report Data Source is set to your query or to `SELECT * FROM yourquery`

You simply change your Textfield ControlSource to concatenate your query parameter names

```
="Between " & [ReportStartDate] & " AND " & [
SELECT myTable.*, ReportStartDate:[Start Date], ReportEndDate]
```